# How to execute a string substitution on multiple files?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, replace, substitution

I have dozens of bash scripts in a certain location (`/subdirectory1`) with the incorrect pathname (`pathname1`) within the file. I would like to somehow replace this pathname with `pathname2` for all of the bash scripts `*.sh` within that subdirectory.

Is there a standard way to do this?

In perl, if I was working with a single file `file1`, I would execute:

```
perl -pi -e 's/pathname1/pathname2/g' file1
```

How would one accomplish this for all files, `*.sh`?

It doesn't have to be in perl, but this is the one way that comes to mind. I suspect there's also a way to do this with other shell scripts and other languages---I will happily edit this question to narrow down the options.

Comment: Change `file1` to `*.sh`? Your question is really unclear.

Comment: Surely `perl -pi -e 's/path1/path2/g' *.sh` will do the trick

Comment: @WilliamPursell That works? ...I'm an idiot

Comment: @WilliamPursell As long as you don't have a space in your file names... The `find` answer below *handles* that curse of modernity.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch The file glob handles whitespace just fine!

Comment: How would one use this perl command for actual pathnames though? If `pathname1` equals `/usr/bin/local/path1` and `pathname2` is `/gpfs/random/user/group/file/path2`, it's a bit confusing to me how to do this correctly...`perl -pi -e 's/"/usr/bin/local/path1"/"/gpfs/random/user/group/file/path2"/g' file1` fails of course

Comment: Use a different delimiter for the s command.  eg `perl -pi -e 's@/usr/bin/path1@/usr/bin/path2@g` *.sh`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: *"That works? ...I'm an idiot"* You really should have *tried* something instead of running straight to SO for help. You would have learned a lot more.

Comment: @Bordon Incorrect. I learn quite a bit from this exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a file glob:

```
perl -pi -e 's@pathname1@pathname2@g' *.sh
```

This will deal with pathological filenames that contain whitespace just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can first run `find` to list the files, then run `perl` or `sed` or whatever on them:

```
find . -name '*.sh' -exec <perl_command> {} \;
```

Note the `{} \;`, which means run this for each of the `find` outputs.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by `<file_pattern>` (I assume `-name "*.sh"`, but I think `<perl_command>` is pretty self explanatory).

Comment: I think it's kind of orthogonal to the question, but sure. Fixed.

Comment: I was thinking another note at the end like, `<file_pattern>` might be `-name "*.sh"` or `-type 'f'` or some kind of combination to indicate the general usage thereof. But putting it inline works too.

Answer (score 2):

Just list all filenames, and they are all processed line by line

```
perl -pi -e 's{pathname1}{pathname2}g' *.sh
```

where `{}` are used for delimiters so `/` in path need not be escaped.

This assumes that the `*.sh` specifies the files you need.

---

We can see that this is the case by running

```
perl -MO=Deparse -ne '' file1 file2
```

which outputs

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    '???';
}
-e syntax OK
```

This is the code equivalent to the one-liner, shown by the courtesy of `-MO=Deparse`. It shows us that the loop is set up over input, which is provided by `<ARGV>`.

So what is `<ARGV>` here?  From [I/O Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: ...  Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line.

where

> `<>` is just a synonym for `<ARGV>`

So the input is going to be all lines from all submitted files.